# WPF Control Background

Tags: xaml, windows-store-apps, winrt-xaml

My WPF control background color is not working in my Universal Windows app. Here is the xaml. The Grid background is working fine, for both grids. The content TextBlocks in the ItemsControl do appear. What am I missing?

```
<Page
    x:Class="Jockusch.Calculator.WindowsStore.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:Jockusch.Calculator.WindowsStore"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:system="using:System"
    mc:Ignorable="d">

  <Page.TopAppBar>
    <CommandBar x:Name="TabBar" IsOpen="True" IsSticky="True">
      <CommandBar.PrimaryCommands>
        <AppBarButton Margin="100,0,0,0" HorizontalAlignment="Left" HorizontalContentAlignment="Right" IsEnabled="True" Name="btnNext" Icon="Next" x:Uid="AppBarNext" Label="Next1"></AppBarButton>
      </CommandBar.PrimaryCommands>
    </CommandBar>
  </Page.TopAppBar>
  <Grid Background="Yellow">
    <Grid.Resources>
      <Style TargetType="ItemsControl">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Wheat">
        </Setter>
      </Style>
    </Grid.Resources>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
      <ColumnDefinition Width="299" />
      <ColumnDefinition Width="100"/>
      <ColumnDefinition Width="366"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
      <RowDefinition Height="200"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <local:WindowsAdAndContentWrapperView Background="Orange" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" x:Name="ContentView"></local:WindowsAdAndContentWrapperView>
    <Grid Background="Brown" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1"/>
    <ItemsControl Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="2">
      <ItemsControl.Items>
        <TextBlock Text="Hello"></TextBlock>
        <TextBlock Text="Where are my colors?"/>
      </ItemsControl.Items>
    </ItemsControl>
  </Grid>
</Page>
```

Comment: And what color do you expect to see? I have smth like this with your code http://prntscr.com/demn2a

Comment: Are you saying your ItemsControl isn't inheriting the setter for background 'Wheat'? Try `TargetType="{x:Type ItemsControl}"`

Comment: Your WindowsAdAndContentWrapperView probably just ignores the Background property? We can't tell unless you show it.

Comment: WinRt apps don't know about x:Type . . . Yes, I'm saying the "Wheat" isn't working. The AdAndContentWrapperView, just nevermind it . . .

Comment: Ohhh sorry, wasn't paying attention to tags. Does it set it if you apply it directly to the control instead of the targettype of the control?

Comment: You mean <ItemsControl Background="Wheat"> . . . ? No, it ignores it. I assume I have to somehow enable background on the control, but I'm not sure how that might be.

Comment: No it's a dependency property of the control according to the docs, there shouldn't be any kind of enabling required. I'm wondering if maybe the items template has a background possibly just covering the background set on the control? I mean the way you have it currently I would expect to work fine.

Comment: This question has too many confounding factors. I've started a fresh question here, which isolates the issue at least: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40946323/itemcontrol-background-color

Comment: Yes, I'm glad to see that you have solved your question.